# Python's requests library timing out but getting the response from the browser

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, user-agent

I am trying to create a web **scraper** for NBA data. When I am running the below code:

```
import requests

response = requests.get('https://stats.nba.com/stats/leaguedashplayerstats?College=&Conference=&Country=&DateFrom=10%2F20%2F2017&DateTo=10%2F20%2F2017&Division=&DraftPick=&DraftYear=&GameScope=&GameSegment=&Height=&LastNGames=0&LeagueID=00&Location=&MeasureType=Base&Month=0&OpponentTeamID=0&Outcome=&PORound=0&PaceAdjust=N&PerMode=Totals&Period=0&PlayerExperience=&PlayerPosition=&PlusMinus=N&Rank=N&Season=2017-18&SeasonSegment=&SeasonType=Regular+Season&ShotClockRange=&StarterBench=&TeamID=0&VsConference=&VsDivision=&Weight=')
```

requests are timing out with the error:

> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py",
> line 70, in get
> return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
>
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py",
> line 56, in request
> return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
>
> File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py",
> line 488, in request
> resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
>
> File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py",
> line 609, in send
> r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
>
> File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py",
> line 473, in send
> raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
>
> ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', OSError("(10060,
> 'WSAETIMEDOUT')",))

However, when I hit the same URL in the browser, I am getting a response.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like the website you mentioned is checking for [`"User-Agent"`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) in the request's header. You can fake the `"User-Agent"` in your request to make it look like it is coming from the actual browser and you'll receive  the response.

For example:

```
import requests
url = "https://stats.nba.com/stats/leaguedashplayerstats?College=&Conference=&Country=&DateFrom=10%2F20%2F2017&DateTo=10%2F20%2F2017&Division=&DraftPick=&DraftYear=&GameScope=&GameSegment=&Height=&LastNGames=0&LeagueID=00&Location=&MeasureType=Base&Month=0&OpponentTeamID=0&Outcome=&PORound=0&PaceAdjust=N&PerMode=Totals&Period=0&PlayerExperience=&PlayerPosition=&PlusMinus=N&Rank=N&Season=2017-18&SeasonSegment=&SeasonType=Regular+Season&ShotClockRange=&StarterBench=&TeamID=0&VsConference=&VsDivision=&Weight="

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36'}
# it's the user-agent of my browser ^ 

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
response.status_code    # will return: 200

response.text      # will return the website content
```

You can find the user-agent of your browser from [here](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent).

Comment: boom! you can find your own `User-Agent` value [here](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent)

Answer (score 4):

if it's still not working, use this header:

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36','Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br','Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,hi;q=0.8'}
```

Answer (score 1):

If other headers does not work, try this **HEADER** , it worked pretty well for me.

```
headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.1.1 Safari/605.1.15","Accept-Language": "en-gb","Accept-Encoding":"br, gzip, deflate","Accept":"test/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8","Referer":"http://www.google.com/"}
```

collected these headers from [this link](https://oxylabs.io/blog/5-key-http-headers-for-web-scraping)